# why the document level script is not working?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am facing a very peculiar problem. I have a pdf in which I have added a document level javascript in order to accomplish condition based text field activation. I have two two text fields, both of them are set as "readonly". There are two more radio buttons in the form as well.

What I want to accomplish, is that if one radio button is clicked, one specific text field will be unlocked/activated by setting "readonly" property to true by a document level javascript. So the document level javascript is as below:

```
function jobtype(type){
switch(type){
case "ill":
this.getField("txt_job2_yearly_salary").readonly = false;
break;
case "income":
this.getField("txt_job2_yearly_salary").readonly = true;
}
}
```

and I have set following javascript action on mouseup event of the radio button:

```
jobtype("ill");
```

but, unfortunately, the function is not triggering. Don't know what is the error in the codes. I have added the pdf file for your kind consideration. Here is the download link:

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2i2pnw05x6lu8cx/Protect%20My%20Family%20-%20Revised-3.pdf?dl=0)

One point to be noted that the original pdf was 14 pages long and have several document level javascript. As my problem was for only one page, I have deleted 13 pages and kept one (which link is given here) which is problematic. But the total size of the pdf remains same as of 14 pages pdf (105 MB). Why that miracle??

Comment: How are you generating the PDF? Is it just a media print of an HTML page, or are you using some library?

Comment: I am creating with Nitro Pro pdf maker 9

Comment: This file is horribly corrupt. I'm looking at it in one of my PDF analysis tools and there are over 1000 hidden layers which I assume belonged to the deleted pages but weren't deleted. There are also 53 fields that are in the file but not represented on the page and at least one of them is throwing a JavaScript error in line 1282... which I can't find. "Type Error f is null"